# Form Validation - JQuery, PHP and MySql - No Data Received

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I've added some validation to my form to avoid any duplicate name entries in my database.  I have a simple `mysql` table with 35 entries.  Using jquery `$.post` I connect to the db, check to see if the name from an `input type='text'` matches a name from the `name` field in the table.  It works pretty well, but if you repeatedly search for names that are in the db, the code eventually breaks and Chrome brings up this message:

[image: no data]

Here is my html:

```
<table id="details_table">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Please choose a username:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" autocomplete="off" maxlength="10"></td>
                        <td id="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Please select your age range:</td>
                        <td><select id="option01" name="age">
                        <option value="0">Please Select</option>
                        <option value="0_14">0-14</option>
                        <option value="15_24">15-24</option>
                        <option value="25_54">25-54</option>
                        <option value="55_64">55-64</option>
                        <option value="65_over">65 or greater</option>
                        </select></td>
                        <td id="age"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Please select your gender:</td>
                        <td><select id="option02" name="gender">
                        <option value="0">Please Select</option>
                        <option value="male">Male</option>
                        <option value="female">Female</option>
                        </select></td>
                        <td id="gender"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Please select your listening device:</td>
                        <td><select id="option03" name="device">
                        <option value="0">Please Select</option>
                        <option value="headphones">Headphones</option>
                        <option value="speakers">Speakers</option>
                        </select></td>
                        <td id="device"></td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
```

Here is my JQuery:

```
$(function() {

    $('#name').keyup(function (evt) {

        $('#text').html("");
        var name = $('#name').val();

        $.post('/context_survey/includes/process_name.php', {name_check: name}, function(rows_returned) {

            if (rows_returned != 0) {
                $('#text').html("<b style='color:red'>Name already exists!</b>");
                $('#name').val("");
            } 

        });
    });
    $('#option01').change(function (evt) {
        $('#age').html("");
    });
    $('#option02').change(function (evt) {
        $('#gender').html("");
    });
    $('#option03').change(function (evt) {
        $('#device').html("");
    });
});
```

Here is my PHP:

```
require_once("connect.php");

if (!empty($_POST['name_check'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name_check'];

    $sql = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE name='{$name}'";

    if ($result = $db -> query($sql)) {
        $num_rows = $result -> num_rows;
        echo $num_rows;
    }

    $db -> close();
}
```

Comment: Does the "code break" still apply if you wait a few minutes before sending another request?

Comment: After a few page refreshes, it comes back as normal.

Comment: Is your search a long running process?  Maybe add an index to the table.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant by this was if you send a request, then leave the page for a few minutes and send another, does it persist? or does your code break when you send requests in quick succession?

Comment: Its extremely fast actually - I'm sure when I get a user to participate in my survey they wont repeatedly enter names that already exist in the table.  Sorry yes, in quick succession.  If this is normal behaviour, its fine.  Its just I thought my methods of code were not quite up to scratch.

Comment: Did you try adding an `else` to print something when the query returns no results?

Comment: I've added a `header("location: error.php")` within an `else` statement to compensate for a query with no results.  Just tried entering names in quick succession and there is no difference.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that the error is normal behavior, however, a solution to the issue, if it is in fact time based, would be to use a time delay of sorts to block multiple submissions from one address or user session etc.

Comment: Yes, its strange.  I've just tried recalling some of the names that are currently in the db at a more slower rate.  It works by giving me the message "Name already exists!", but only up to about 5 names then hangs, then gives me the "no data" message.  Then after a few mins everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`No data received` error means that your server closed connection before even sending response headers. It has totally nothing to do with your code. Or the server is badly configured, and  closes connection on `CGI` error - in this case `PHP` interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - is there any chance you could point me in the right direction in terms of what to read up on this subject?  I've tried searching for some of the stuff you have mentioned, but I can not find anything that specifically matches my problem.  To note, Its a paid web hosting service - GoDaddy.